# Postgres/SQL - Find records that when joined with another table only have ONE joined record specifically

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have two tables, where I represent users that have many dogs:

USERS

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa |
| 2 | bbbb |
| 3 | cccc |
| 4 | dddd |

DOGS

| id | user_id | breed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | poodle |
| 2 | 1 | lab |
| 3 | 2 | lab |
| 4 | 3 | bulldog |
| 5 | 4 | lab |
| 6 | 4 | lab |

I want to find users who only have one and only one dog of 'lab' breed.

i.e this being the desired result:

USERS

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | bbbb |

So in this case, only the dog id 3 matches the requirement because its user only has one dog and it is a lab.

`SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN dogs ON users.id = dogs.user_id WHERE dogs.breed = 'lab'`

where to go from here? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, and that this would be a common requirement but my google-fu is failing me at this moment. Looking for postgres oriented solutions but any help is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schema and insert statments:

```
create table USERS (id int, name varchar(20));
 insert into  USERS values(1    ,'aaaa');
 insert into  USERS values(2    ,'bbbb');
 insert into  USERS values(3    ,'cccc');
 insert into  USERS values(4    ,'dddd');

 create table DOGS(id int,  user_id int, breed varchar(20));
 insert into DOGS values(1  ,1  ,'poodle');
 insert into DOGS values(2  ,1  ,'lab');
 insert into DOGS values(3  ,2  ,'lab');
 insert into DOGS values(4  ,3  ,'bulldog');
 insert into DOGS values(5  ,4  ,'lab');
 insert into DOGS values(6  ,4  ,'lab');
```

Query:

```
  SELECT u.id,u.name FROM USERS u
     INNER JOIN DOGS d
     ON u.id = d.user_id 
     WHERE d.breed = 'lab'
     and exists (
                select 1 from DOGS where DOGS.user_id=d.user_id 
                group by user_id having count(*)=1
                );
```

Output:

```
     |id | name|
     |---|-----|
     | 2 | bbbb|
```

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc6971e944f56494afc5878ce5f40827)*

Answer (score 1):

One method is aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select u.id, u.name
from users u join
     dogs d
     on d.user_id = u.id
group by u.id, u.name
having count(*) = 1 and        -- one dog
       min(d.breed) = 'lab';   -- it's a lab
```